# Smart cards and their files

Tags: filesystems, smartcard, javacard, apdu, globalplatform

As far as you know, we can list the applets that reside in a Java Card using tools such as `GlobalPlaformPro` as follow:

```
GP: gp -list
AID: A000000003000000 (|........|)
     ISD OP_READY: Security Domain, Card lock, Card terminate, Default selected
 CVM (PIN) management

AID: 010203040506 (|......|)
     App SELECTABLE: (none)

AID: 0102030405 (|.....|)
     Exe LOADED: (none)

GP:
```

The questions are:

1. Where are these applets in the card? (in the `MF`? or in a `DF`?)
2. Who choose it? (the directory that applets get installed to)
3. Is there any way to see the AID of `MF` and all the other `EF`s and `DF`s of card?
4. What is my current directory? Can I change it?
5. And how I can create a `DF`?

I tried to create a `DF` with regard to the commands defined in `ISO7816-part9` as below, but I receive errors only!

[image]

```
GP: gp -s 00e00000 -d -v
# Detected readers from SunPCSC
[*] ACS CCID USB Reader 0
SCardConnect("ACS CCID USB Reader 0", T=*) -> T=0, 3Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SCardBeginTransaction("ACS CCID USB Reader 0")
Reader: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (60ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000
Auto-detected ISD AID: A000000003000000
A>> T=0 (4+0008) 80500000 08 78FF1563FF46D23B
A<< (0028+2) (166ms) 0000116001008A790AF9FF020138983B77E636B6C12237B087216130 90
00
Host challenge: 78FF1563FF46D23B
Card challenge: 0138983B77E636B6
Card reports SCP02 with version 255 keys
Master keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
Sequnce counter: 0138
Derived session keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:4544C6282153F89C2144A2C49784FCC3
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:017010873EFEC7A838D54C06A9AC2B40
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:A719298F33D1FECCD89334BA93FC3E70
Verified card cryptogram: C12237B087216130
Calculated host cryptogram: C1CF507F2B48CAEA
A>> T=0 (4+0016) 84820100 10 C1CF507F2B48CAEA7FFA4D851F5C0B1D
A<< (0000+2) (86ms) 9000
A>> T=0 (4+0008) 04E00000 08 08C1F21746AB8A16
A<< (0000+2) (24ms) 6E00
SCardEndTransaction()
SCardDisconnect("ACS CCID USB Reader 0", false)

GP: gp -s 00e000000a003400010101ffff0080 -d -v
# Detected readers from SunPCSC
[*] ACS CCID USB Reader 0
SCardConnect("ACS CCID USB Reader 0", T=*) -> T=0, 3Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SCardBeginTransaction("ACS CCID USB Reader 0")
Reader: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
More information about your card:
    http://smartcard-atr.appspot.com/parse?ATR=3Bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

A>> T=0 (4+0000) 00A40400 00
A<< (0018+2) (55ms) 6F108408A000000003000000A5049F6501FF 9000
Auto-detected ISD AID: A000000003000000
A>> T=0 (4+0008) 80500000 08 1B81F8C4D44CC86A
A<< (0028+2) (166ms) 0000116001008A790AF9FF0201391213E503ADE77D8CC6A546AE3537 90
00
Host challenge: 1B81F8C4D44CC86A
Card challenge: 01391213E503ADE7
Card reports SCP02 with version 255 keys
Master keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F
Sequnce counter: 0139
Derived session keys:
Version 0
ENC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:F02DB909386D90DA638ACA4AB92501E1
MAC: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:FD6A2A492566BDE1940C54127C022126
KEK: Ver:0 ID:0 Type:DES3 Len:16 Value:98FAA5CF01E133557688FD90E1571FAC
Verified card cryptogram: 7D8CC6A546AE3537
Calculated host cryptogram: 14C22B8CE836A4D4
A>> T=0 (4+0016) 84820100 10 14C22B8CE836A4D4C2F1C20A8CD56F8C
A<< (0000+2) (85ms) 9000
A>> T=0 (4+0018) 04E00000 12 003400010101FFFF0080B9174FA320EEC470
A<< (0000+2) (24ms) 6E00
SCardEndTransaction()
SCardDisconnect("ACS CCID USB Reader 0", false)

GP:
```

Why I can't create my desired file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Where are these applets in the card? (in the MF or in a DF?)**

Consider each Java Card application to be a DF directly below the MF. Though, be aware that Java Cards only make use of parts of the ISO 7816-4 file system concept and that the MF itself is not necessarily selectable by default.

**Who choose it? (The directory that applets installed there)**

The Java Card specifications partially define this (through the way how the SELECT (by AID) command is defined; other than that Java Cards do not make use of the file system concept).

**Is there any way to see the AID of MF and all the other EFs and DFs of card?**

From an API perspective, only DF names can be AIDs. Consider AIDs to be DF names that comply to a specific format. MF and EF have file IDs. However, as there is no file system concept on Java Cards, there are no addressable MF, EFs by default (you can *emulate* this functionality though applet code). 
So the only listable components that are on a Java Card are applets and applet packages (which you already found to be listable though Global Platform card management for your card).

**What is my current directory? Can I change it?**

See above. No file system concept -> no notion of a "current directory". If you are within an application (selected applet), the applet can emulate a file system. In that case things like a "current" directory" depend on the applet implementation.

**And how I can create a DF?**

By installing (and making selectable) an applet.

Comment: Good answer, to make it clear again: Specifications are not mandatory at all and just because ISO7816-4 defines a tetxbook File system does not mean Javacards have one. If you want 7816 compliant file system you need to code that as part of your applet

Comment: Does that mean all the commands that mentioned in the 7816-9 (Card-Management), must implement in the applets? (And JCRE/Card Manager will not recognize them)?

Comment: @Abraham JCRE handles only SELECT (by AID/DF name) and MANAGE CHANNEL commands. The GlobalPlatform card manager application (when selected) handles all commands neccessary to perform card management according to the GlobalPlatform specifications.

Comment: @Abraham: If you desire more complete file system functionality, you could chose a non-Javacard (sometimes this card category is called "native" cards, but the supported functionality depenes on the manufacturer).

Comment: @guidot Thanks. How program for those cards typically? Is there any capability to develop  applications for them? Is there any multi-application capability in them? Is MultOS a "native" card? Does they meet GP specifications also? (I know they are different with each other, But how are the typical native cards?)